# Get form name inside master page using IEnumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, ienumerator

I want to get the form name from the rendered HTML. I have placed the aspx page inside a master page. I have the following code where I am passing the name of the page as parameter. But my code is returning the null since ctlEnumerator.Current is showing the master page name. What changes should I do in my code to get the form name? Thanks in advance.

```
private HtmlForm __getHtmlForm(System.Web.UI.Page page)  
{  
IEnumerator ctlEnumerator = page.Controls. GetEnumerator();  
while (ctlEnumerator.MoveNext())  
{  
object curr = ctlEnumerator.Current;  

if (curr is HtmlForm)  
{  
return ((HtmlForm)curr);  
}  
}  
return null;  
}
```

Comment: What _"name"_ do you want, the name of the type of the page, the title of the page or what else? Also, you talking of names, pages and masterpages but the method you're showing returns a `HtmlForm`. Completely unclear.

Comment: I have a master page and I placed an aspx page inside it. I want to get the form name from the redered html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the `HtmlForm` of the  currrent page, you could use this static method which does not even require an argument:

```
public static System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm GetHtmlForm()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context != null)
    {
        Page currentPage = context.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (currentPage != null)
            return currentPage.Form;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you get it in the master in this way:

```
string currentFormName = GetHtmlForm().Name;
```